# How can I output the result of "Get-Service" to a HTML file?

Tags: html, powershell

I am using "Get-Service -Name $Service |Select-Object -Property Status" to see if a Windows service is running. I need to output the result to a simple HTML file.

This is my test script, using the Workstation and Themes services as a test:

$Services=@("Workstation","Themes")

foreach ($Service in $Services)
{Get-Service -Name $Service |Select-Object -Property Status |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Body "

## Service Status

Running

" -Title ServiceStatus
Out-File -FilePath C:\ServiceStatus.htm}

This runs without error and creates the HTML file, but the file is blank.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is going into `Out-File`? Is another VERTICAL LINE needed?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Your `Out-File` call isn't connected to the pipeline that is meant to provide its input; place a `|` after the `ConvertTo-Html` call.